# Problem with rotating an object with face to another one. [C++]

Tags: c++, math, 3d, rotation

I want to rotate an object with the face side to the center of another one, but I have some problems with it: when I try to rotate an object to another one and it lies on X axis, it works properly [first two screenshots], but when I try to rotate it as on the screenshot, everything breaks down [second two screenshots].

[image: Before1]
[image: After1]

```
Before1:
1 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 
0 0 1 0 
0 0 0 1 

After1:
0 0 -1 0 
-0 -1 0 0 
1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1
```

[image: Before2]
[image: After2]

```
Before2:
0 0 -1 0 
-0 -1 0 0 
1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 

After2:
0 0 -0.707107 0 
0.5 -0.5 0 0 
0.707107 -0.707107 0 0 
0 0 0 1
```

Here's my code:

```
void ConcreteObject::faceObjectTo(ConcreteObject otherObject) {
    Vector<double> temp = {0, 1, 0};

    Vector<double> forward = otherObject.getCenter() - this->getCenter();
    forward.normalize();

    Vector<double> right = temp.cross(forward);
    right.normalize();

    Vector<double> up = forward.cross(right);

    Matrix<double> newMatrix = this->getTransformMatrix().getCurrentState();

    newMatrix(0, 0) = right[0];
    newMatrix(0, 1) = right[1];
    newMatrix(0, 2) = right[2];

    newMatrix(1, 0) = up[0];
    newMatrix(1, 1) = up[1];
    newMatrix(1, 2) = up[2];

    newMatrix(2, 0) = forward[0];
    newMatrix(2, 1) = forward[1];
    newMatrix(2, 2) = forward[2];

    TransformMatrix newObjectMatrix(newMatrix);

    this->setTransformMatrix(newObjectMatrix);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to normalize right, there's no reason for temp and forward to be orthogonal, hence even if they are unit vectors, their crossproduct need not be.

Comment: All I need to do is normalize right? 
I just tried to do it both before and after I calculate vector "Up", but nothing has changed :(